# What are the differences between Joust 3v3 and Duel 1v1?

Tags: smite

In ranked matches you can play Duel matches.  I **[read](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Joust)** that for the Joust mode:

> There are also 2 Ranked variants of this game mode: A standard 3v3 Joust and a 1v1 variant called Duel.

What is different about the Duel map?  For example, does it include the Bull Demon King?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Duel and Joust game modes both use the same map. So yes, the Bull Demon King is there in both modes, as is everything else.